# Show that $\mathbb{C}^n = U \oplus V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In $\mathbb{C}^n$ there are given vector subspaces:
$U = \{\vec{u} \in \mathbb{C}^n: u_{1} + u_{2} + \dotsb + u_{n} = 0\}$ and $V = \{\vec{v} \in \mathbb{C}^n: v_{1} = v_{2} = \dotsb = v_{n}\}$.
Show that $\mathbb{C}^{n} = U \oplus V$. For given vector $\overrightarrow{x} \in \mathbb{C}^{n} $ determine vectors $\overrightarrow{u}, \overrightarrow{v}$ that $\overrightarrow{x} = \overrightarrow{u} + \overrightarrow{v}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\vec{x} = (x_1, \ldots, x_n) \in \mathbb{C}^n$ and define $a := \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i$. Then

$$ \vec{x} = (x_1 - a, \ldots, x_n - a) + (a, \ldots, a). $$

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped but I got only one problem - how to show that U and V intersection is ${0}$?

Comment: @piternet Since $\dim U=n-1$ and $\dim V=1$, you don't need to prove it. However, if $(a,a,\dots,a)\in U$, then $na=0$, so…

Comment: I would need to prove it only when dimensions of U and V were equal?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the matrix
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & \dots & 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
It is clear that $C(A^H)=V$ (column space) and, moreover, $N(A)=U$ (null space). It is a standard result that, for any $m\times n$ matrix $B$, we have $\mathbb{C}^n=N(B)\oplus C(B^H)$. In particular for $B=A$.